# How can I effortlessly block + unblock air vents, on the wall near the ceiling?

Tags: air

##### While my kids are away at university, how can I swimmingly block the lone air vent in each of their rooms? When my kids come home from university every weekend or so, I need to remove the barricade just as readily!

Please don't ask me to swivel each of the white metal laths manually every time, which wastes too much time and energy! Each slat is too stiff to twirl.

[image]

![image]

Comment: Why do you need to block the vent?  Wouldn't turning off the thermostat be much easier and a lot more effective?

Comment: @RayButterworth My apartment still has people, like husband and me! I need to block the vent so that air isn't wastefully ventilated to 2 empty rooms. But I still need the thermostat to ventilate the rest of the apartment!

Comment: Ah, so that one thermostat controls the air in *all* the rooms. From the picture it looked like each room has its own HVAC unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get you some *magnet tape*, this comes on a spool and has stickytape on one side. with it you can make things like refrigerator magnets. If the grille frame is made from steel, magnet tape will stick to it and you can attach the tape to a thin piece of plastic or cardboard so it will cover up the vent and stay in place with the magnets.

Comment: Magnets were my first thought, but you got it on the mat first.